# Python __init__(self,**kwargs) takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm creating a simple class in Python 3.6 that should accept keys,values from a dictionary as arguments

my code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for a in kwargs:
            self.a=kwargs[a]
            for b in a:
                self.a.b = kwargs[a][b]
Test = MyClass( {"group1":{"property1":100, "property2":200},\
    "group2":{"property3":100, "property4":200}})
```

My code returns an error:

> TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I expect Test.group2.property4 to return 200

There are many similar questions I found however main problem everywhere is absence of "self" inside **init** method. But I have it.

Could someone explain the reason for this error?
Thanks

Comment: You told `__init__` to  take an arbitrary number of keyword arguments, but call it with two positional arguments (one of them being implicitly provided by Python as a reference to the object created, the other one being a dictionary)..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pass the parameter(s) as an unpacked dict, not as a single positional argument:

```
MyClass(**{"group1":{"property1":100, "property2":200},\
    "group2":{"property3":100, "property4":200}})
```

Comment: equivalent: `MyClass(group1={"property": 100, ...)`

Comment: Thank you. And then it appears a KeyError 'g' on line "self.b = kwargs[a][b]"
So it doesn't want to open a dict in side a dict.
Also if I try to left in the code only one for loop, dir(MyClass) returns (... a) instead of (...group1, group2). it means self.a doesn't convert itself into self.group1 when initializing.

Comment: Does your suggested code works for you or it also gives a KeyError?
MyClass(**{"group1":{"property1":100, "property2":200},\
    "group2":{"property3":100, "property4":200}})

Comment: The problem is not with that line of code. It's with the for loop. `for b in a` should be `for b in kwargs[a]`, since `a` is a key not a dictionary. There are other problems with your code tho...

Comment: As the result I found possible to __init__ nested dictionaries to kwargs using: 
`Class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            val = value
            if isinstance(val, dict):
                val = MyClass(**val)
            setattr(self,key,val)`

Comment: If you already have a dictionary with they keywords, you could just pass your arguments like so:  `MyClass(group1={"property1": 100, "property2": 200}, group2={"property3": 100, "property4": 200})`